# can't start default network, is there a way to run dnsmasq for both local and kvm?

Tags: kvm, dnsmasq, libvirt

I can't start KVM since I use dnsmasq on my laptop as a DNS cache server,

[image]

So, I'm wondering if this can be merged to the server I'm running.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, add

```
bind-interfaces
except-interface=virbr0
```

to some file in `/etc/dnsmasq.d`. (that's what Ubuntu's `libvirt-bin` package (at least) does automatically now)